# jQuery.ajax: How do I get the data to send easily?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have lots of forms on a project I'm working on.

All the forms pretty much go through AJAX.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: ???,
        success: function(msg){
        }
    });
```

I want to be able to intercept these POST's and instead run them through AJAX.

The code is written into a method that will be reused.

So the question is: How can I select all the data that was going to be passed, turn it into a query string and insert it into the `data: ???,` part.

Thanks

Comment: So... all your forms pretty much go through AJAX, and you want to run them through AJAX instead?  Also, look into `.serialize()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to intercept the `submit` event. Bind an event handler on your `<form>` elements. When encountered, stop its propagation and its default behavior by returning `false` from within that event handler.

Now, you can create your `.ajax()` request in that handler to. To create a serialized form of your form-data into a query-string, use jQuerys `.serialize()` method on that form aswell.

For instance:

```
$('#myFormId').on('submit', function( event ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Or just create that as delegated event, which handles all of your forms, like

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function( event ) {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use serialize method:

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/